# Как в nvim настроить общий буфер обмена с системой?

Tags: linux, vim

Как сделать так чтоб nvim копировал в буфер обмена, а не в локальный буфер?

Answer (score 0):

эм, просто <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> для копирования и <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> для вставки всей строки. Больше примеров - https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-can-i-copy-text-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim

Comment: К сожалению, это не работает

Comment: я только что у себя проверил - работает чудно. Может какие то плагины/настройки?

Comment: возможно, вим скомпилирован  без поддержки буфера обмена. Тогда оно не работает. Если у Вас убунта/дебиан, то может установлен vim-tiny, а не vim или vim-nox

Comment: я использую neovim, думаю нужна оговорка,   что я использую его на удаленном хосте через ssh

Comment: neovim он в большинстве случаев работает похоже на обычный vim, а вот ssh - вот это меняет все. Вот тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694516/vim-copy-mac-over-ssh есть разные решения, вплоть до обращения по ssh  к основной машине и помещению в буфер обмена.